# Preciso fazer meu arquivo Javascript enxergue os arquivos vue e axios

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Criei faz pouco tempo um projeto Laravel que está usando VueJs e Axios, e em seguida enviei para o servidor Heroku, porém algo de estranho aconteceu, a pagina está com a visualização muito estranha está dando erro na primeira linha do meu arquivo app.js é lá onde se encontra todos os métodos vue e axios que estou utilizando

Como você pode ver o erro é de na primeira linha do vue;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu arquivo app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
            el: '#crud',
            created: function() {
                    this.getRegistros();
            },
            data: {
                    registros: [],
                    newDesc: '',
                    newPreco: '',
                    newQtdQuartos: '',
                    newTipo: '',
                    newFinalidade: '',
                    newLogradouroEndereco: '',
                    newBairroEndereco: '',
                    preencherRegistro: {
                        'id': '',
                        'descricao': '',
                        'preco': '',
                        'qtdQuartos': '',
                         tipos: ''  ,// acho que meu problema está aqui******
                        'finalidade': '',// acho que meu problema está aqui******
                        'logradouroEndereco': '',
                        'bairroEndereco': ''
                    },
                    errors: []
            },

            methods: {
                    getRegistros: function() {
                        var urlRegistro = 'imovels';
                        axios.get(urlRegistro).then(response => {
                                this.registros = response.data
                        });
                    },
                    editarRegistro: function(registro) {
                        /*  alert(registro.tipos); */

                             this.preencherRegistro.id = registro.id;
                             this.preencherRegistro.descricao = registro.descricao;
                             this.preencherRegistro.preco = registro.preco;
                             this.preencherRegistro.qtdQuartos = registro.qtdQuartos;
                             this.preencherRegistro.tipos = registro.tipos;
                             this.preencherRegistro.finalidade = registro.finalidade;
                             this.preencherRegistro.logradouroEndereco = registro.logradouroEndereco;
                             this.preencherRegistro.bairroEndereco = registro.bairroEndereco;
                             console.log(this.preencherRegistro.tipos);
                             $('#edit').modal('show');
                    },
                    updateRegistro: function(id) {
                            var url = 'imovels/' + id;
                            axios.put(url, this.preencherRegistro).then(response => {
                                    this.getRegistros();
                                    this.preencherRegistro = {  'id': '',
                                    'descricao': '',
                                    'preco': '',
                                    'qtdQuartos': '',
                                     tipos: ''  ,
                                    'finalidade': '',
                                    'logradouroEndereco': '',
                                    'bairroEndereco': ''  };
                                    this.errors   = [];
                                    $('#edit').modal('hide');
                                    toastr.success('Tarea actualizada con éxito');
                                            }).catch(error => {
                                                this.errors = 'Corrija para poder editar con éxito'
                                            });
                    },
                     createRegistro: function() {
                         var url = 'imovels';
                         axios.post(url, {
                            descricao: this.newDesc,
                            preco: this.newPreco,
                            qtdQuartos: this.newQtdQuartos,
                            tipos: this.newTipo,
                            finalidade: this.newFinalidade,
                            logradouroEndereco:  this.newLogradouroEndereco,
                          bairroEndereco:    this.newBairroEndereco
                         }).then(response => {
                             this.getRegistros();
                             this.newDesc = '';
                             this.newPreco = '';
                             this.newQtdQuartos = '';
                             this.newTipo = '';
                             this.newFinalidade = '';
                             this.newLogradouroEndereco = '';
                             this.newBairroEndereco = '';
                             this.errors = [];
                             $('#create').modal('hide');// efetuar a execução
                            toastr.success('Novo imóvel criado com sucesso!');
                         }).catch(error => {
                                this.errors = error.response.data
                         });
                     },
                    deletarRegistro: function(registro) {
                             var url = 'imovels/' + registro.id;
                             axios.delete(url).then(response => {
                                 this.getRegistros();
                                 toastr.success('Registro excluído com sucesso');
                             });
                    }
            }
        });
```

Acredito que esteja errado são esse import´s

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
```

tenho que colocar nos caminhos certos, veja onde estão meus arquivos **vue** e **axios**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que não esteja tão difícil de me ajudar, só não faço porque tenho pouca experiência com programação.

A pasta **public** está na raiz do projeto, dentro da pasta public tem a pasta **lib** e dentro da pasta lib tem os arquivos **vue** e **axios**.

Comment: O Problema possivelmente está na configuração do `webpack`, o seu projeto está em uma `URL` direta ou dentro de uma pasta? está assim (`www.url.com`) ou (`www.url.com/projeto`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import axios from 'axios' está correto, você fez o npm install axios, está usando ele via npm? Acredito esta pode ser o erro.

Comment: não é esse o problema.

Comment: desculpe resolvei sim.

Comment: Será que poderia dá uma olhada nesse por favor?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251520/como-fazer-o-projeto-laravel-enxergar-o-arquivo-axios